# Facebook like in business model

Tags: web-development, facebook, marketing, facebook-application

I have a website "www.example.com" and a Facebook page for www.facebook.com/example/123456
My website need active users.

Now in my website I would like a like button, now the question is:
From a marketing point of view, where do I point my like to; to my website or to my Facebook page, having in mind that when a user likes your page any posts on that page gets shared on the user's wall, bringing more potential users.

Comment: Do you mean a facebook icon or graphic on your website and where to link it? Or the actual facebook like or share button they provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your looking to gain users for your website then I would suggest having it like "www.example.com" rather than your Facebook page as this is where you want to drive people to.

How ever I also think a good idea would be to offer users an incentive to like your Facebook page such as "Like us on Facebook for 5% of all clothing", this means that people are also likely to like your Facebook page as there is an incentive. But first I would recommend getting people to share your website on Facebook, give it a bit of exposure and online presence.

**Guide on how to create an incentive like page:** http://smallbusiness.chron.com/create-like-incentive-tab-facebook-29079.html

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the best option would be a facebook page. What reason is there to point it back to your website? A like button is always associated with facebook. Could you clarify your question please, and fix some of the grammatical errors ("...page for www.facebook.com/example/123456 my website need active users.") I would have said that as a comment, but I haven't built up the points too.